# Differences between using AppleTV 4K device, AppleTV app and AppleTV+?

Tags: appletv

This is my first foray into the world of AppleTV and also my first 4K television and I could use a little help orienting myself.

I have a (43") Samsung LED 4k 'smart' television on order (I believe it's the 2023 TU43CU8000K). At the moment I watch only streaming services (Netflix, HBOMax, PrimeVideo and another European service, as well as YouTube on occasion).  I have no great desire to have all my data captured by the Samsung (though if it's unavoidable, so be it), so my thought was to have the [AppleTV 4K device](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-tv/apple-tv-4k) connected directly to the HDMI port of the Samsung and use the Samsung as a 'dumb' TV.  (I've been told that the Samsung may protest in some way and want to be connected to the WiFi network, but that there are ways to eventually disconnect it -- if you have any tips, that would be appreciated).

But I was told the Samsung has the AppleTV app already installed.  What does this mean exactly?  Is this an app for the AppleTV+ streaming service?  Does it have anything to do with the AppleTV 4K device?

Comment: I removed part of the question to keep it focused. You can ask a new question for other issues, but most of the ones I removed are either answered on support.apple.com or most likely off-topic here.

Comment: I use an AppleTV 4K connected to a Sony TV via HDMI.  I turned off all the  Google nonsense and use it as a dumb TV.  I purposely didn’t connect it to WiFi or Ethernet; the ATV is, though. The only issue I have is about once a month a modal pops up on the screen prompting me to “finish setting up my TV”.  I ignore it as it goes away after 10 seconds. You should be able to do the same with your Samsung.

Comment: Thanks to all!  It worked great. The only issue is the television set had major blooming issues so back to the shop it went. Now on the search for a better set. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Apple TV+](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/) is a streaming service for movies and series.
- The [TV+ app](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-app/) on the Samsung TV gives you access to the content provided by Apple TV+.
- The [Apple TV](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-4k/) *box* is a dedicated hardware box which runs TV+ but also a lot of other apps (e.g. Netflix, Youtube etc) and games. It connects to your TV via HDMI.

So if you want to reduce the amount of data Samsung can collect from you, and/or want to use other streaming services, an Apple TV box is a good solution for this.

Comment: Worth noting there may be a difference in the content available on the ATV app depending on the hardware platform. On my LG TV I can watch all subscription content plus any purchases. On the ATV app on my Sky box (UK satellite TV and VOD provider) I can only watch subscription content. I assume this is because the purchased content would compete with Sky’s own offerings.

Comment: You say that the Apple TV box runs a number of apps, such as NetFlix, etc. what if I have a streaming service that I view through a browser but which doesn’t have its own app?  Will that work?  I live in Europe and it’s a country specific service with “artier” content.

Comment: @Cerulean They may have an app, or you could use Airplay to play it via the box from any macOS/iOS device

Comment: Another advantage of the Apple TV device itself is that (if you enable data to be shared with the TV app on the Apple TV device) the “Up Next” section of the app shows all of the movies and TV shows that you have started watching. It works for every single service I have come across, except for Netflix, and user-added libraries in Plex. If you watch a lot of TV shows, this is the absolute best way to keep track of where you are, and when new seasons come on, across just about any streaming service, not just Apple TV+.